# How to enable SSl Certificate on subdomain in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services

`SSL` Certificate is already enabled on my main domain but now I want to enable `SSL` on my subdomain too, So how can I enable on my subdomain, I am using `AWS services`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to generate an SSL for your subdomain you will need to go through the ACM process again in the region(s) you're operating in.

When you specify the domain for the certificate you can either specify an absolute subdomain (`foo.example.com`) or specify a wildcard domain (`*.example.com`).

Once you have specified this you will need to go through the standard validation approach to have the certificate approved.

As an additional point going forward, AWS supports adding multiple domains to a single certificate so you could add the root domain (`example.com`) and the wildcard subdomain (`*.example.com`) to the same certificate which would allow you to use the same certificate.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to edit an existing certificate to add more domains or a sub-domain of an already existing domain on an ACM certificate.

In case you wish to obtain a certificate for a new domain or sub-domain you can either have two separate certificates for the domain and sub-domain or delete the older certificate and request a new certificate with both the domain and sub-domain on the certificate.

A single certificate can hold `domain.com` & `*.domain.com`. Also the same certificate can also have `domain1.com` & `*.domain1.com`

Source https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=931119